# apply openmp to this loop if possible

Tags: loops, fortran, openmp

I'm trying to add openmp to this code due to the amount of time that it takes to execute.  Anyway to speed this loop up would be greatly appreciated.  I've already attempted a solution but it never executes on a thread number higher than 0.

```
!$OMP PARALLEL do private(pm25_tmp,pm10_tmp,V,aerombin,LVL,ROW,COL,isec)                                                                          
       write(*,*) 'num procs:',omp_get_num_procs()
       write(*,*) 'num of thread:',omp_get_num_threads()
       write(*,*) 'thread number:', OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
       do LVL = 1, NLAYS3D
         write(*,*) 'THIS IS THE LVL FOR PSO4', LVL
         DO ROW = 1, NROWS
           DO COL = 1, NCOLS
             pm25_tmp = 1.*PSO4(COL,ROW,LVL)
             pm10_tmp = 0.*PSO4(COL,ROW,LVL)
             if (PSO4(COL,ROW,LVL).gt.1.E-10) then
              call mode2sec(pm25_tmp,pm10_tmp,aerombin,pmtot,
 &        JDATE,JTIME,COL,ROW,LVL)
              DO isec=1,nsections
                V = ngasemis + isec+8*5
                EMIS1_SEC(COL,ROW,LVL,V) = aerombin(6,isec)
                aerombin(6,isec) = 0.0
              END DO
              end if
            end do
          end do
       end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

Here is the makefile I'm using:

```
FC = ifort
M3LIB       =  /scratch3/NAGAPE/arl/Barry.Baker/cmaq502/CMAQv5.0.2/lib
icldir      = ${M3LIB}/ioapi_31/Linux2_x86_64ifort

# IOAPI LIBRARIES
IOAPI_INC  = ${M3LIB}/ioapi_31/fixed_src
IOAPI_LIB  = ${M3LIB}/ioapi_31/Linux2_x86_64ifort
NETCDF_LIB = ${M3LIB}/netCDF/Linux2_x86_64ifort
#LIB1   = /usr2/tmp/lib/ioapi/ioapi_22/Linux2_x86pg
#LIB2   = /usr2/tmp/lib/netCDF/Linux

#LIBS = -L$(LIB1) -lioapi -L$(LIB2) -lnetcdf
LIBS = -L$(IOAPI_LIB) -lioapi -L$(NETCDF_LIB) -lnetcdf
EXE  = senex_rwce3_8sec

# Set compiler version dependent flags and LINKTOOL

# Fortran flags

FLAGS2  = -openmp -I$(icldir)
#
#  Object files
#
OBJS  = senex_rwce3_eightsec.o \
       senex_mode2sec_eightsec.o \
       ../integrator/qk15.o   ../integrator/qk41.o   ../integrator/qpsrt.o \
       ../integrator/qag.o    ../integrator/qk21.o   ../integrator/qk51.o \
       ../integrator/r1mach.o ../integrator/qage.o   ../integrator/qk31.o \
       ../integrator/qk61.o   ../integrator/xerror.o

$EXE: $(OBJS)
        $(FC) $(FLAGS2) -o $(EXE) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
```

Comment: what command line are you using to compile this code?

Comment: i've updated with adding the makefile I used and the putting the !$OMP parallel do directly before the do loop as suggested by redcrash below.  It did not seem to make a difference.  At the beginning of the subroutine I do a use omp_lib as well

Comment: Check the value of the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable. Some OpenMP runtimes default to one thread if the variable is unset. Some sites explicitly set that value to 1 by default to prevent users from unknowingly taking over entire nodes.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing some vital information such as which compiler you use and as casey has commented, how do you compile the application. Additionally, your OpenMP construct seems illegal because

```
  !$OMP PARALLEL DO
```

should appear immediately before the DO loop.

That being said, you could try the following test to see whether your system can succesfully generate OpenMP applications. You'd need to tune the FC for your Fortran compiler and FFLAGS for the Fortran flags within the Makefile. Note that in the example I'm providing I'm adding -fopenmp because that tells gfortran to enable OpenMP in the code (otherwise, the OpenMP pragmas are ignored!).

The output of the code below is the following in my old Lenovo T400 with 2 cores:

```
# ./test
Serial: num procs:           2  num of threads =            1  thread num =            0
Parallel: num procs:           2  num of threads =            2  thread num =            0
Parallel: num procs:           2  num of threads =            2  thread num =        1
```

Notice that omp_get_num_procs() gives how many processors have been detected by OpenMP. The routine omp_get_num_threads() informs about the number of threads that are running **within** the parallel region and returns 1 when it is invoked outside any parallel region. Finally, omp_get_thread_num() returns the thread identifier (from 0 to omp_get_num_threads()-1) that is executing the parallel region and returns 0 if it is invoked outside a parallel region.

File **test.f90**

```
      PROGRAM TEST
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER I, &
        omp_get_num_procs, &
        omp_get_num_threads, &
        omp_get_thread_num

      write(*,*) 'Serial: num procs:',omp_get_num_procs(), &
        " num of threads = ", omp_get_num_threads(), &
        " thread num = ", omp_get_thread_num()
!$OMP PARALLEL DO 
      DO I = 1, omp_get_num_procs()
      write(*,*) 'Parallel: num procs:',omp_get_num_procs(), &
        " num of threads = ", omp_get_num_threads(), &
        " thread num = ", omp_get_thread_num()
      ENDDO

      END
```

File **Makefile**

```
FC = gfortran
FFLAGS = -fopenmp

test: test.f90
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: I was able to use this to run on my system but I cannot for the life of me to get this to work for the code I'm tryingto speed up.  I also updated the post with some of your suggestions and I included the makefile.  I'm using the intel compiler and have the appropriate flag -openmp instead of -fopenmp

Comment: btw when I run my code putting the calls to write the number of processors threads and thread number out I am getting 48 processors and 1 thread

Comment: Do you have OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable set to 1?

Comment: Right before running the script I do a      "setenv OMP_NUM_THREADS 12"

Comment: Barry, can you double check whether the code compiles fine? I have tested with Intel Fortran compiler (versions 13.x and 14.x) to execute the write(*,*) immediately after the $OMP PARALLEL DO directive and I get the following error: test.f90(11): error #7644: The statement or directive following this OpenMP* directive is incorrect.

Comment: redcrash,  I have modified it so that the call to the write(*,*) commands occur after the first do loop.  The program seems to compile fine and run.  It just takes a long time currently in serial mode.

Comment: So what is the value for NLAYS3D? Is it possible that this first loop only iterates once? If so, you can move the OpenMP pragma to the next DO loop.

Comment: NLAYS3D is the number of vertical levels.  The value is 22.  I print this out and it cycles through the levels properly

Comment: It looks like you're only passing -openmp when generating the binary through FLAGS2, right? You need to compile every object (.o) file with -openmp also. Can you check that?